# How would I get this to repeat without getting stuck on invalid input?

Tags: c++

quick question.

How would I get this code to loop itself so that it keeps asking the question, but still allow a different action when a non-numeric input is given?

```
int main()
{
    int temp = 0;
    while (temp =1, 10)
    {
        int amend_numb = -1;
                cout << "\nWhich amendment? "; 
                cin >> amend_numb;
            if (amend_numb == 1)
            {
                cout << "a.\n";
            }
            if (amend_numb == 2)
            {
                cout << "b.\n";
            }
```

I attempted to put it into this while statement, however if I enter anything other than an integer into the cin, then it does an infinite loop of constantly repeating the cout statement. Is there any way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: I dont really understand the question.  Do you want this to repeat forever, or for a certain number of loops

Comment: not an integer you mean float or string?

Comment: @urnotsam I want the question to repeat for ever, but with the code I have right now, if I don't put in an integer then it goes into an infinite loop of asking the question with no breaks or anything.

Comment: Question still unclear, if you want it to repeat forever then whats wrong with it goes into an infinite loop of asking the question

Comment: @Steve I just updated the code. The program will work exactly how I want it to, until I enter anything other than an integer. If I enter 'x' or '.' or '6.4' then it will continually spam the question.

Comment: @Joe You have no code to read anything other than an integer from `cin`. So if the user enters something other than an integer, it never gets read. You just keep trying to read an integer, despite the fact that you now know that's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

> while (temp =1, 10)

Although the expression is syntactically correct, it may not perform the way you think:
1. Assign `temp` to 1.
2. Disregard the value returned from the assignment (because of comma operator)
3. Remaining expression is 10, which is nonzero, so loop continues.

The general rule of thumb is to use a `for` loop for known quantities of iterations:

```
for (temp = 1;   // assignment
     temp < 10;  // continuation expression
     ++temp)     // iterator incrementing
{
  // loop content
}
```

When interacting with Users, you want the loop to repeat until an exit condition is satisfied.

```
  unsigned int temp = 0;
  while (temp != 0)
  {
    cout << "Enter amendment number, 0 to quit: ";
    cin >> temp;
    if (temp > 0)
    {
      switch (temp)
      {
        //...
      }
    }
  }
```

Some people like a *forever* loop with a `break` statement:

```
  unsigned int temp = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    cout << "Enter amendment number, 0 to quit: ";
    cin >> temp;
    if (temp == 0)
    {
      break; // terminate loop
    }
    switch(temp)
    {
      //...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true)
{
//your code
}
```

simple

and then for your none integer input, you should really do a type cast if you think the user might not provide expected input. Since cin would return a string so you should use string to int cast, something like "stoi" if your compiler supports it or look up c++ string to int I am pretty sure you will get bunch answers.

Edit: if the user might enter anything that is not a number, then you better check for error, put a try and catch statement between the cast, if it fails then tell the user input is not valid.

Comment: c++ try and catch for just int input looks difficult to explain, could you please give a small example?